How to Add Space Between Two Texts in a Mantine Badge Component?
I use Mantine UI + Talwind CSS to write Components.
I'm trying to add space between two texts in a Badge component so that one text is aligned to the left and the other to the right. Here is my current code:
<div>
<Stack>
 <Badge fullWidth variant="light" color="gray" tt="none" h={30} style={{ display: 'flex',    justifyContent: 'space-between', alignItems: 'center' }}>
   <Group>
        <GolosText size="16px" c="black" fw={600}>Size:</GolosText> 
        <GolosText size="16px" c="black">L</GolosText>
   </Group>
 </Badge>
</Stack>
</div>

However, both texts are aligned next to each other. I want "Size:" to be on the leftmost side and "L" on the rightmost side of the Badge.
My badge
Expected result
I tried to use
 <div style={{ flexGrow: 1 }} /> and <div style = {{flex:1}}/> 

between texts
Also, I used Space element from Mantine Core, but it does not give enough padding.
I used hardcoded Width for Space element, and it partly solves my problem, but it does not make the space responsive, leading to buggy UI
<GolosText size="16px" c="black" fw={600}>Size:</GolosText>
        <Space w="930px" /> 
 <GolosText size="16px" c="black">L</GolosText>


Create a minimal reproducible example of the problem! There are tons of places where you can do that!

You can achieve desired output by doing changes as below.
You can check example here -> Example
<Badge
  fullWidth
  variant="light"
  color="gray"
  tt="none"
  h={30}
  sx={{ ".mantine-Badge-inner": { width: "100%" } }}
>
  <Group sx={{ width: "100%", justifyContent: "space-between" }}>
    <GolosText size="16px" c="black" fw={600}>Size:</GolosText> 
    <GolosText size="16px" c="black">L</GolosText>
  </Group>
</Badge>

